# What document I can ask for to prove my job as a Freelancer?

Tags: freelancing

I've been working as a freelancer for 4 years. Now I want to move to a permanent job.

The company where I'm applying for this permanent job is requesting a document that prove my work of at least 1 year.

In the last 2 years of my freelancer work, I've been working using 85% of my time for an important client.

What document I can ask for from this client to prove my work? Since most of my time I spent developing projects for him (Taking into account that at no time we had a contract involved).

Is there any document similar to a "Certificate of employment" that matches my situation?

Comment: Did you ask the company?  What are they expecting?

Comment: Have you considered using your bills to the client? And copies of the checks they used to pay them?

Comment: Also do you have any tax documents?

Comment: Did the client mail you a 1099? You can also ask the client for a written reference where your client certifies that you did work for said client for two years, starting from such and such a date to the present time. That should be enough. What your prospective employer is looking for is confirmation of your claim that you worked as a freelancer, and I believe these two documents or even just the letter of reference should do it. Again, state to HR that you did 85% of the work for the client lest HR have you chase down all of your former clients for confirmation :)

Comment: I personally find it difficult to believe you've done enough work to support yourself for years without having any tax documents.

Comment: If you worked as a contractor, shouldn't there actually be a contract?

Comment: You might also try to get a personal reference from your major client. A written reference would be best, as that will always be available for future reference, but even if he only agrees to give a phone reference he could confirm that you have been doing work for him all that time.

Comment: Why do you not have your company accounts?

Comment: invoices and letters are ok but do not undervalue your own word, the same way we buy products by only reading the ad the same way companies have to trust us

Answer (score 13):

You have a number of options (I'll list ordered best to worst based on my personal experience)

1. A letter from one or more of your clients that simply says you worked for them, how long, and it what context.
2. Tax Documents establishing significant money traded hands in a business manner 1099 or similar
3. Invoicing or billing documents

**Do not** show them emails, receipts, or other documents that contain potentially sensitive information without the written approval of the client. You can potentially get yourself into serious legal trouble depending on the nature of the information and your local laws

Comment: Surely redacted receipts with the amounts blacked out would be fine? It's the date and name of employer that's important.

Comment: @Styphon I would say it's "probably" fine. Likely it's fine in the majority of the US, but laws in what financial transactions are considered private and confidential get vary murky as they vary drastically from state to state. It's extremely unlikely this particular scenario will be a problem, but better to always play it safe when it comes to potential litigation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the US, the following should help.  It could be less helpful, depending on your location and employment requirements.

When you did the work, you billed them and they paid.  On the money you received, you paid taxes.  You also have emails or other forms of communication where you discuss the requirements and plans.  There are people at that company that you did the work for.

All of that, or parts of that, can prove your employement.  You were employed by yourself, as a freelancer, but you were still employed.  You have your tax forms, paid invoices.  As well, you can contact your main client (or any of the others), and ask if they will provide a reference when needed.